# what does facebook black hole email mean?

Tags: facebook

My application is an applicant track system, we publish jobs to Facebook job board.

Facebook will post the applicants' info to me at a certain interval, I noticed a portion of applicants' emails look like this:

```
blackhole-mahgf2lecesygo20gwmidylu-1619232918@devnull.facebook.com
```

when I try to save them as the login email, the email validation fails.

- Does anyone know the meaning of this email?
- In which case, will the user's email be a black hole?

Comment: With both the words "blackhole" and "devnull" in there, I guess it is probably safe to assume that mails send to those addresses won't go anywhere.